# How do I properly do Haskell pattern matching on a list?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I'm trying to work through the Haskell exercises at the bottom of [this page](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/defining-types-streamlining-functions.html). The one I'm working on is #7. Here's the problem:

Define a function that joins a list of lists together using a separator value.

Here's the type signature:

```
-- file: ch03/Intersperse.hs
intersperse :: a -> [[a]] -> [a]
```

And here's the way it's supposed to behave:

```
ghci> :load Intersperse
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Intersperse.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
ghci> intersperse ',' []
""
ghci> intersperse ',' ["foo"]
"foo"
ghci> intersperse ',' ["foo","bar","baz","quux"]
"foo,bar,baz,quux"
```

So this is what I came up with:

```
intersperse :: a -> [[a]] -> [a]
intersperse a [] = ""
intersperse a [x] = x
intersperse a [x:xs] = x ++ a ++ (intersperse a xs)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
intersperse.hs:4:24: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[a]’ with actual type ‘a’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          intersperse :: forall a. a -> [[a]] -> [a]
        at intersperse.hs:1:16
    • In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘x’
      In the expression: x ++ a ++ (intersperse a xs)
      In an equation for ‘intersperse’:
          intersperse a [x : xs] = x ++ a ++ (intersperse a xs)
    • Relevant bindings include
        xs :: [a] (bound at intersperse.hs:4:18)
        x :: a (bound at intersperse.hs:4:16)
        a :: a (bound at intersperse.hs:4:13)
        intersperse :: a -> [[a]] -> [a] (bound at intersperse.hs:2:1)
```

I'm really new at Haskell, so I don't really understand this error. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

Got it to work with this:

```
intersperse :: a -> [[a]] -> [a]
intersperse a [] = []
intersperse a [x] = x
intersperse a (x:xs) = x ++ [a] ++ (intersperse a xs)
```

Turns out there were a few things wrong.

Comment: Your final solution is quite idiomatic. If you want, you can also remove the parentheses in `... ++ (intersperse a xs)` since application (function call) has the highest precedence. It is common to write e.g. `f 3 + g 2 - h 5` without parentheses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern `[x:xs]` matches only with a list of length one, whose single element is nonempty (matches with `x:xs`). E.g. it matches with `[[1,2,3]]` with `x=1` and `xs=[2,3]`. It does not match with `[[1],[2,3]]`, `[]`, or `[[]]`.

You want `(x:xs)` instead. This can match `[[1,2],[3],[4,5]]` with `x=[1,2]` and `xs=[[3],[4,5]]`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but replacing the brackets with parentheses in `[x:xs]` still returns the same error, only this time at `4:29` instead of `4:24`.

Comment: @Jono The above answer indeed fixes only one error. The next error arises since in the RHS, `a` is not a list, and you are using it with `++`. Try using `... ++ [a] ++ ...` instead.